# Income code 37 from 1042-S in 1040NR

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I have received 1042-S which contain income code 37, which is the return of capital. This amount is not taxable to me and the amount withheld was already repaid to me. Is there a need to report it somewhere in the 1040NR (which line or schedule).

I am a non resident alien. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No need to report as income.  Return of capital doesn't go anywhere on the tax return.  This is true for residents & non-residents.